# NSMutableArray doesn't populate tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have few table view controllers and I want selections from them  to be shown on "ResultTableViewController". I also have array that collects the selected data and when i finally push it to the "ResultViewController" it shows only the last selection. Please help

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    firstarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //array with questions
    [self.firstarr addObject:[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //collects the data properly

    BodyDetailViewController* vc =[[BodyDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BodyDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.someArray = firstarr; //some array - ViewController with Results.

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Post the code you are using..

Comment: Yeah man, post your code

Comment: You definitely need to provide more detail on this to get a useful answer. Could you edit the question and add your implementation of the datasource methods of the table view shown by ResultViewController?

Comment: try this vc.someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:firstarr];@JackMilo

Comment: Make sure you are not initializing the array in the BodyDetailViewController. It happened to me when I started my dev in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this line :

```
firstarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Because you're initializing your NSMutableArray each time you're selecting a cell, so all the data previously stored is erased and `vc.someArray` is getting an array with only your last selection, that's why ;)

Init your NSMutableArray outside the method, in your `viewDidLoad` for example

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
firstarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //array with questions
```

...creates a new array.  Whatever was in `firstarr` previously is gone when you do a new selection.

Either create the array once somewhere else (when the object is initialized?) or append its content to `vc.someArray` instead of replacing it.